# How to find the list of employees in age between 25-35 and have held the designation of Manager or Lead using stream api?

Tags: java, java-stream

*class has got fields as String Name , int age , List designation*

Comment: How would you do it with loops? Can you show what you have tried? Also, don't describe your code, instead show your code.

Comment: Please [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72301865/edit) the description of the problem question: add the `Eployee` class, *share your code-attempt*, provide an example of the *input/output*. It's **mandatory** if you expect to get a helpful response. The current version of the question doesn't demonstrate any effort and very likely to be closed, I kindly advise you to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
List<Emplyes> empFiltred = employes.stream().
            filter(p -> p.getAge() > 25 && p.getAge() < 35).
            filter(p -> p.getDesignations().contains("Manager") || p.getDesignations().contains("Lead")).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
```